# mac nvram from ubuntu

Tags: mac

How can I read and write nvram values on a 2014 mac mini from ubuntu?  ie the equivalent of MacOS's nvram program.

The particular thing I am trying to set is SystemAudioVolume to get rid of the annoying chime, but I also want to change the boot order.

Answer (score 0):

nvramtool, but it seems that some settings are unaffected even when changing their value in nvram from ubuntu (SystemAudioVolume might be one).

Answer (score 0):

This is for disabeling startup sound, but same method should work with some other things too:

Reboot with an OSX installation disc or Recovery HD

Start the Terminal

Issue the command:

```
/usr/sbin/nvram SystemAudioVolume=%01
```